# Connect to another computer on same network in php

Tags: php

I have to connect to another computer and download a file and fetch it to my computer on the same network through PHP. How can I do this? Please Help.

Comment: You want to download a file via http from a server on the same network? Why dont you use file_get_contents ?

Comment: This has *nothing* to do with CakePHP, please use only relevant tags.

Comment: @user2360915 yes, i have to download it via http.

Comment: @burzum ok, please tell me with core php

Comment: Posted an example below. For below to work, you need allow_url_fopen set to true.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
$url = 'http://192.168.1.1/test.html';
$file = 'test.html';
file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($url));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP FTP 
http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

or CURL.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

alternatively you can execute a wget in shell_exec

Comment: @user2360915 can we connect using Ip address?

Comment: Yes, this can be done with all three methodws (http, FTP or CURL).

Comment: @Timothy Groote I am using this code to connect 
<?php
$ftp_server = "192.168.1.68";
$ftp_username="webner";
$ftp_userpass="123456";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
if($login)  
echo "hey connected to remote server";
else
echo "Not connectd to remote server";

ftp_close($ftp_conn); 
?>

Comment: That should work, you might still need to tell it which port to use. the default port for FTP is 21, so you'll need `192.168.1.68:21`
Also make sure an actual FTP server *is running* on that machine.

Comment: @Timothy Groote how would i know that FTP is working on remote machine.

Comment: @Timothy Groote I am getting Could not connect to 192.168.1.68:21...

Comment: @Rupzz Seriously?
That IP Address is a local address. it must be running on your local network, meaning that either you are its administrator, or the administrator is someone you can talk to. you might want to just ask *them*.
A good way to determine *if* that machine is running FTP is to just connect a client to it on port 21. if it fails, it either is not running FTP, or it's running it on another port.

Comment: Telnet to that ip >telnet 192.168.1.68 21